# grid view:How to get : value of a column,set a colum visible or hidden, insert into another table if a cell value is equal to smth

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I would like to know:

1. 1.How to get the value of a column in a grid view? I always want to get the value from column 3 always the 3rd cell .
2. 2.How can I hide a column?
3. 3.On update a cell , I want to get all the values from the selected row and insert them into another database table ( called Edited values )  with the same
   columns. And if I edit another cell from the same table ( the main )
   , the row moved in the other table (Edited values) will be deleted and all the
   values from the selected row to be copied in another database table.

SO basically I have a table with 5 columns . If I edit a certain column . all the values from the selected row will be copied into another table called : Edited values . and when I come again on the same row and edit another column , the row with the values from the table : edited tables will be deleted and all the values from the current row will be copied into another database table called : Finished editing

Comment: thanks <3 , now back to work:D

Comment: is this all during the same session or does it need to save edited values long term. For instance, if you edit a row today and close the browser then come back to it tomorrow, do you still need to see the past edited values?